# value for api response

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I need to set a value for this value that is inside a dropdown of an api response.

```
    },
    "images": {
        "icon": "https:\/\/fortnite-public-files.theapinetwork.com\/emote\/594a01c56a48c816359c78ff82fcd259.png",
        "background": "https:\/\/fortnite-public-files.theapinetwork.com\/image\/d3c7281-7ea64be-5953632-71ab90e.png",
        "item": "https:\/\/fortnite-public-files.theapinetwork.com\/image\/d3c7281-7ea64be-5953632-71ab90e\/item.png"
    }
```

I need to set a value for "background" but I can't figure out how. THe code I'm using is this:

```
  if item:
    itemimage = item['images']
```

That just returns all the code inside "images". I need it to return "background" inside "images"

Answer (score 1):

The "images" itself is a dictionary, so you can access the key of background within that dictionary using:

```
itemimage = item['images']['background']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been experimenting forever and I can't believe it was this easy

Comment: Happens to me all the time. Glad I could help! I recommend this video to get you off the ground working with JSON: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N6a-VLBa2I